# Xamarin.Forms Listview issue on IOs with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms app which works fine on Android and UWP and even Windows 8 or Phone 8. Now I got a mac to test the IOs version of it and noticed that all pages where a **ListView** exists which is bound to an **ObservableCollection** fail. They fail in a way that the app does no longer respond (not even "Back" works).
In the debugger I could see that the collection is properly filled and that the UI does not refresh itself (**IsVisible** is bound to the list count).

Then I removed the IsVisible settings in XAML and defined it as True as fixed value. The app displays an empty list and I get no entries shown after the list got filled.

The Visual Studio Console output has nothing at that point in time except the app start stuff.

Is there any other log which one can look at for IOs Apps running from Visual Studio against the Mac? And what could be the reason for this? I mean it works on all platform except IOs.

Meanwhile I stripped down the XAML code to the bare minimum and then it worked. So I removed the deletion one after the other and finally it was this XAML code that breaks the whole page without any warning:

```
                    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <MenuItem Clicked="OnMore" Text="{common:Translate Text=SwipeContextMoreButtonText}" />
                        <MenuItem Clicked="OnDelete" Text="{common:Translate Text=SwipeContextDeleteButtonText}" IsDestructive="True" />
                    </ViewCell.ContextActions>
```